# SQL Server : Bulk insert with a parameter

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm trying to do a bulk insert into SQL Server like this:

```
BULK INSERT [ETL].dbo.Loans_Staging
FROM 'C:\Data\QN5101_20220105'
WITH
    (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
     ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a')
```

The problem here is that the date after the underscore is going to change from day to day, therefore I will need to have some kind of wildcard parameter, ideally something like below setup will work (although it doesn't):

```
BULK INSERT [ETL].dbo.Loans_Staging
FROM 'C:\Data\QN5101_*'
```

Is there an option to do this?

Comment: You can't use a wildcard, and you can't use a variable; the value after the `FROM` *must* be a literal string to the exact path of the file, as shown in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). If you need a dynamic path, you'll need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Someone or something is generating the file - change it to use a single file name? Or add your own preprocessing that copies or renames the file? Use some imagination - lots of ways to approach this.